# Old GamePadState xbox controller

Tags: c#, xna, gamepad

So I'm trying to do something quite simple using a gamepad that I have done using a keyboard before. And that is to create an old state to record what button was pressed on the last update.

So when using the keyboard I had a code that looked something like this:

```
oldKeyboard = currentKeyboard;
```

This was placed at the end of my update and meant that on the next update I could have if statements like such

```
if (currentKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A) &&(oldKeyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.A))
{
guy.drawRect.X ++;
}
```

The problem I'm having now is that I'm using a Xbox Gamepad in my code and I just don't know what the correct code is. Currently this is what I have and it isn't working :P. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 void ShipUpdate(GamePadState Curr, GamePadState Old)
    {
        Curr = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

        if (Old.ThumbSticks.Left.X > 0.0f && (Curr.ThumbSticks.Left.X == 0.0f))
        {
            move = MoveState.Still;
            guy.srcRect.X = 0;
        }

        Old = Curr;


    }
```

I've stripped all non essential code here so this is J.E.E.P

Comment: I managed to fix this issue myself.


The key was in the following line

    void ShipUpdate(GamePadState Curr, GamePadState Old)


Once I removed the gamepad states from these line everything worked just fine. Here is the corrected line.

    void ShipUpdate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually updating your old state. Since you are passing those as arguments and the GamePadState is actually a structure,

```
 Old = Curr;
```

updates only the local copy of the 'old' variable. Pass them by reference like

```
 void ShipUpdate(ref GamePadState Curr, ref GamePadState Old)
```